# I'm looking for an application/text editor that

Tags: regex, replace, increment

can best help me systematically modify the "replace" field of a regex search as it encounters each match.

For example, I have an xml file that needs the phrase "id = $number" inserted at regular points in the text, and basically, $number++ each time the regex matches (id = 1, id = 2, etc) until the end of the file.

I know I could just write a bash/perl/python script or some such, but I'd like it to be at least moderately user-friendly so I could teach my intelligent (but less technically-inclined) workers how to use it and make their own modifications.  Regexing is not a problem for them.

The closest I've come so far is Notepad++'s Column Editor and 'increase [number] by' function, but with this I have to write a separate regex to align everything, add the increments, and then write another to put it back.  Unfortunately, I need to use this function on too many different types of files and 'replace's to make macros feasible.

Ideally, the program would also be available for both Windows & Linux (WINE is acceptable but native is much preferred), and have a 'VI/VIM input' option (if it's a text editor), but these are of secondary importance.

Of course, it'd be nice if there is an OSS solution, and I'd be glad to donate $20-$50 to the developer(s) if it provides the solution I'm looking for.
Apologies for the length, and thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

emacs (version 22 and later) can do what you're looking for.  See [Steve Yegge's blog](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/06/shiny-and-new-emacs-22.html) for a really interesting read about it.  I think this should work:

```
M-x replace-regexp
  Replace regexp: insert pattern regexp here
  Replace regexp with: id = \#
```

`\#` is a special metacharacter that gets replaced by the total number of replacements that have occurred so far, starting from 0.  If you want the list to start from 1 instead of 0, use the following replacement string:

```
id = \,(1+ \#)
```

Comment: "Oh yeah! Good ol' C-x M-c M-butterfly..." http://xkcd.com/378/

Original poster here.  Thanks so much for your suggestion!  Clearly my bias against Emacs has blinded me, but I'll try it out later tonight (downloading it now... arrrrgh!)  My only concern is the user-unfriendliness-- fingers crossed!

Comment: well, the stubborn VI man will tip his hat to Emacs this time.  Kudos and many thanks to you-- it works as advertised.  The interface & shortcuts will take some getting used to, but I should be able to create some customized key bindings, yes?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

JEdit can probably help you:
http://www.jedit.org/

you can do all kinds of regex and even bean result based replacing with it.

Comment: Hi, original poster here.  Thanks for the suggestion!  I use Jedit frequently myself, and the regex is indeed nice, but I'm not aware of any such function with beanshell-- can you or anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: To answer your question: http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/search-replace.html#id2558292

Comment: yes, I learned about beanshell before both from the link you provided and http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/writing-macros-part.html   Unfortunately, I still haven't found a simple solution to the original problem.  I hope it exists because Jedit is one of the three editors I use most frequently

Answer (score 1):

[UltraEdit32](http://www.ultraedit.com/) is great and I believe it has the features you need.  There is a free 30-day download so you can make sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you want an app available on Windows/Linux, but there's another solution on Mac : [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), and it's free.

Comment: Hello, original poster here.  Thanks for the suggestion!  I've been a fan of BBedit and TextWrangler for years, but again, no one in my laboratory uses a mac  :-(   Also, I'm unfamiliar with any increment function on Textwrangler... what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UltraEdit32](http://www.ultraedit.com/). It's very good. Not free, but available in Windows, Linux and Mac platforms. It has regex based search & replace.

Answer (score 0):

This [script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1199) should let you do what you want in [Vim](http://www.vim.org).

Comment: Hello, original poster here. Thanks for the suggestion! I have no doubt it'll work as advertised, but unfortunately it's probably way too complicated for my workers :-(  I'll definitely file it away for my own use though!

Answer (score 0):

Vim functions can do the incrementing number trick and aren't too hard to write.  For example the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip971) says how to do this.  See also `:h sub-replace-\=`.

```
function! Counter()
    let i = g:c
    let g:c = g:c + 1
    return i
endfunction

:let c=1|%s/<\w\+\zs/\=' id="' . Counter() . '"'/g
```

We've probably left user-friendliness long behind at this point but Vim's Ruby support can do this kind of thing easily too:

```
:ruby c=0
:rubydo $_.gsub!(/<\w+/){|m| c += 1; m + ' id="' + c.to_s + '"'}
```

Or Perl:

```
:perl $c=1
:perldo s/<\w+/$& . ' id="' . $c++ . '"'/eg
```

Comment: Hi, original poster here. Thanks for the suggestions! Those all look like they'd do the trick, but I'm just thrilled I've taught them regex and they can launch firefox in KDE.  Their job doesn't require serious computer skills, so I think their eyes would glaze over at this  :p

Answer (score 0):

To me, this sounds like it might be a job for awk, rather than a job for an editor.

Comment: Hi, original poster here.  Thanks for the suggestion!  I agree that awk/grep/sed would ultimately work nicely, but again, I'm afraid it's a bit too much to ask for my workers.